# Opengl-es camera can see an object?

Tags: opengl-es

I have a camera (pos, dir)
and
I have an object (x,y,z)

How can I detect when the object can see with my camera?

Comment: Your question is unrelated to OpenGL (ES), because OpenGL doesn't deal with such things. It's merely geometry. The keywords you're looking for are "frustum culling" and "projection volume culling".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have enough info. You need to know camera frustum. Than you calculate if the object is inside frustum. Learn more here:

http://www.lighthouse3d.com/tutorials/view-frustum-culling/ 
http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_transform.html